# What unsupervised methods are used for sampling a dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, sampling, unsupervised-learning

I have a dataset of 21 classes. Each class has different number of samples. I want to sample an specific number of samples from each class. For example 50.

I thought of using K-means to cluster 50 samples from each class.
What other methods have you used?

Thank you

Comment: You seem to want stratified random sampling.

Comment: @tchakravarty But how do you know you are not losing interesting samples when doing random selection?